# Geometry Nodes. How can I offset an instanced Nurbs path so that it will go away from its tangent

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I want to make some short spikey hair, I want to have it go a little to the sides like a person's hair would. if I were to have the strands coming from a flat plane facing upward I could just set an offset by a random vector made by a noise texture break the xyz and plug x any y into a combine xyz and use that as a vector. but how do I do essentially do the same thing with a curved surface. this is what I have for a setup.[image]